# Hypernym for numbers like 10, 100, 1,000, and so on

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an umbrella term for numbers like 10, 100, 1000, 100000 etc?

Comment: Power of ten...?

Comment: Depending on context, which we do not have, the term *round number* could be appropriate.

Comment: @Mari-LouA even power**s** of ten

Comment: @mplungjan You do have to admit that ten is an odd power of ten. Then again, so is a thousand. But a hundred or a million is an even power of ten. :)

Comment: I meant “not only power of ten, even powerS of ten”

Comment: @mplungjan A thousand is the third power of ten, and three is an odd number. A hundred is the second power of ten, and two is an even number.

Comment: Even = not only!

Comment: Not only power singular but plural powers. What do you call these numbers? I call them powers of ten

Comment: @mplungjan: ...but I think an hyperonym is generally singular if the hyponyms are singular?

Comment: I call them *columns* (as in, the tens column, etc).